# SPSS Find & Replace Syntax with Numeric Variables?

Tags: spss

Some variables in my dataset have a Value Label that includes (Void). For example:

Variable name : # of cars

Values:
0
1
2
3 or more(Void)

Is there a syntax I can use to perform the same task? Or alternatively, is there a method within SPSS to get rid of all the (Void)'s in one stroke?

When I click/highlight the Values column, and Find/Replace, I can manually replace (Void) with [empty] to only clear (Void) and leave the rest of the labels intact. I have to click this several times depending on the number of variables containing the phrase. I don't seem to have an option to click once and have it repeat until the phrase is no longer found in any variable's values.

I also tried a version of this syntax used for text variables to no avail:

```
do repeat vr=yourfirstvar to yourlastvar.  
compute vr=replace(vr, "na", "").  
end repeat.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to search and replace value labels directly from syntax. As a workaround, the following syntax creates a dataset with a table of the value labels. Now we can search and replace, and then automatically create a new syntax that attaches the corrected value labels back to the original values:

First just creating an example dataset with value labels:

```
data list free/aa bb cc (3f1).
begin data
    1 2 3     2 4 5     6 2 1
end data.
value labels 
    aa
    1 "hello"
    2 "bye(Void)"
    3 "here"
    /bb
    1 "aba(Void)"
    2 "ima"
    /cc
    6 "here"
    7 "there"
    8 "(Void)in between".
dataset name orig.
```

Now for the solution:

```
* sending value labels to the output and capturing them through OMS.
DATASET DECLARE  vals.
OMS /SELECT TABLES /IF COMMANDS=['File Information'] SUBTYPES=['Variable Values'] 
    /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV OUTFILE='vals'.
display dictionary.
omsend.
dataset activate vals.

* Now we create a syntax to change the labels and correct them. 
string cmd(a50).
compute cmd=concat("add value labels ",var1, " ", string(var2,f2), ' "', replace(label, "(Void)", ""), '".').
write out="c:\users\eli\remove void.sps" /cmd.
exe.

* the syntax is created, we go back to the original data and insert it.
dataset activate orig.
insert file="c:\users\eli\remove void.sps".
```